# how to Enable or Disable Etag in the magento website

Tags: performance, magento, etag

how to **Enable** or **Disable** **Etag** in the magento website to imporve the performance of website.

Please share if any video or documents available for the same.

Answer (score 0):

To disable it, you must add 'FileETag none' into your '.htaccess' file or uncomment it (remove the '#' symbol before this text).